# Escaping '$' for a range of Perl arguments

Tags: perl

I would like to do the equivalent of:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   arg[i] = arg[i].Replace("$", @"\$");
}
```

in Perl.  What would this look like in Perl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is *only* dollar sign `$` you wish to escape I would go with [depesz's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80168/depesz) solution with a simple substitution. However, perl has a built-in function to handle escaping meta characters, `quotemeta`:

```
@arg = map quotemeta, @arg;
```

Note that this escapes all meta characters, which may not be what you want.

Comment: It's actually removing a dollar sign and the number after it.  "blah$100" becomes "blah00".

Comment: @kmarks2 I'm not sure what you mean. This code does not do that.

Comment: $TLP if I have "@arg = map quotemeta, @arg; $data = "$ARG[0]"; print $data;" and $ARG[0] is "string$100", "string00" is outputted to the console. The assignment actually involves some mix of literals and ARGs, but I simplified it for example's sake.

Comment: @kmarks2 Well, this code does not do anything that could cause that, so the error most likely lies in that assignment of yours. Try using the Data::Dumper module to print your `@arg` array before and after quotemeta. e.g. `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@arg`

Comment: @kmarks2 Also, `@arg` is a completely different variable from `@ARG`. Variable names are case sensitive.

Comment: @kmarks2, you are mistaken, If that printed `string00`, it's because `$ARG[0]` was `string00`, not `string$100`.

Comment: I don't think I am mistaken, @ikegami.  I'm running the script right now as we speak.  It can be found at http://pastebin.com/QmWJSwd1 .  If I call it at the command line like: "  ./script "$100"  "  it outputs "00".

Comment: @kmarks2 You are mistaken. That looks like a shell interpolation error, since you are using double quotes. Try `echo "$100"` in the shell to see for yourself, or just print @ARGV. Run the script with `./script '$100'` and you should get the expected result.

Comment: @kmarks2 Also, it is quite unnecessary to quote the variable and to assign it to another variable. You can simply do `print $ARGV[0]`.

Comment: Ahhhh.  Okay, thanks @TLP.  What damage can switching from double quote args vs. single quote cause in the places where my script is called?  The only reason I wanted to use any quotes was to preserve spaces contained in single arguments.

Comment: If you only have strings, it should be fine. Use single quotes when you want the literal string, double quotes when you want interpolation.

Answer (score 6):

```
for ( @arg ) {
    s/\$/\\\$/g;
}
```

Should do the trick. If you insist on working only on first 10 args, change first line to:

```
for ( @arg[0..9] ) {
```

Comment: I am being pedantic, but you could use `:` instead of forward slashes to make it a bit more readable. i.e. `s:\$:\\\$:g;`.

Comment: I'm not sure how is that more readable. If I was working on slashes in the regexp, it would make sense - because it would decrease number of backslashes, but in here? Anyway. If one doesn't want to use /, I think that {} is better, like s{}{}. It has great functionality because it's paired.

Answer (score 1):

In Perl, you can use `map` to transform a list into another list. So you could say

```
@arg = map { s{\$}{\\\$}g; $_; } @arg;
```

You could also use the postfix form of `for`, since the default loop variable is an alias to the original value.

```
s{\$}{\\\$}g for @arg;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
foreach my $thing( @arg ) { 
    $thing =~ s{\$}{\\\$}g;
}
```

If you want to be super-verbose, you can do the C-style loop:

```
for ( my $i = 0; $i < @arg; $i++ ) { 
    $arg[$i] =~ s{\$}{\\\$}g;
}
```

...but that's not especially Perlish.

Comment: Your first suggestion with `map` will not do what you want. It is the return value of the code block that is returned to the list, not the content of `$_`. You want `s{\$}{\\\$}g; $_`

Comment: `@arg = map { s{\$}{\\\$}g; $_; } @arg;` is just a silly way of writing `map { s{\$}{\\\$}g; } @arg;` (which is just a silly way of writing `s{\$}{\\\$}g for @arg;`). You know that `$_` is an alias, right?

Comment: Proper `map` usage: `@arg = map { (my $s=$_) =~ s{\$}{\\\$}g; $s } @arg;` or `@arg = map { s{\$}{\\\$}gr } @arg;`. You could also use List::MoreUtils's `apply`: `@arg = apply { s{\$}{\\\$}g } @arg;`.